# User changed user id in AD (got married) but old name is still displayed in asp.net app

Tags: asp.net, authentication, active-directory

I have a user who got married and changed id from MJones to MSmith however MJones still displays on welcome page of my app. I use Context.User.Identity.Name to get the user id. The AD team said it was changed and only has the old name for Exchange purposes. I have had her clear cookies and temp files as well as form data in IE. Any ideas on why this is happenning and what I can do to resolve?

Oh my app uses windows authentication for security.

Answer (score 0):

Has her login ID actually changed, or did the AD folks just change the name for the account. The login account is a separate thing - the Name property on a WindowsIdentity is the account name, not the user's forename/surname.

Comment: id actually changed. She now logs onto the network as MSmith.

Comment: How long ago did they change the account name?